# Why Satellite Assembly not use in Winform Application

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, localization, devexpress

I've got a winform application which uses it's own mechanism for localization. It doesn't use Satellite assemblies and I am not sure why. Are there any reasons that Satellite assemblies not suitable for winforms application localization?

Comment: It works but you have to create Resx file of yours.

Comment: Hard to guess, but look for assignments to the CurrentUICulture property in the code.  A demo feature, never gets used in practice since users don't switch their native language on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases Localization via Satellite Assemblies is the best possible option. This is a standard practice and it should be followed unless you have good reasons not to.

The good reasons for creating your own solution:

- Your User Interface is dynamic that is texts often change quite a lot (i.e. depending on the customer). In such case it makes sense to keep translatable resources and corresponding translations in the database
- The translators you are cooperating with do not know the first thing about XML and technical translations, therefore having them translating resx files is too dangerous. In such case you might want to implement your own solution, i.e. having translations in config-like files
- You are the boss, you know i18n better than subject matter experts and you are going to correct this lame implementation of Microsoft engineers. Not you of course but original developer - usually somebody with huge ego or somebody suffering from Not Invented Here syndrome might think it is a good idea to come with "better" solution

For the real reason why the application uses non-standard approach, you probably need to ask the original developer (or somebody else who might know the answer). From my experience it would be one of the reasons listed above, quite often the third one.

Answer (score 1):

I did following steps.

1. Create Window Form Application
2. Add Folder Resource
3. Add New Resource1.resx
   Add One Item
4. Copy Resource1.resx and Paste as Resource1.da-DK.resx
5. Now build .. if you look at Debug folder it contain directory "da-DK" that is satelite assembly of resource for "da-DK".

This way i used in many application.

Also you have run application in specific culture.

Answer (score 1):

Using *Satellite Resource Assemblies* is a common approach for developing world-ready applications. To learn more about *localization*, refer to [Localizing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68135h5.aspx) in MSDN.

check DevExpress documentation about this and various windows applications are localized using Satellite Assembly

Have you checked these on documentation:
[Localizing DevExpress .NET Windows Forms Controls](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1866)
[Localizing Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746982/localizing-windows-forms)
[Improving Performance of Localized Forms](http://windowsclient.net/articles/localizationfilter.aspx)

There is a book named `.NET Internationalization: The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications` in this context..